# Yama LSM seems to do nothing. RHEL/Centos 7.5

Tags: linux, security, selinux, lsm

The Yama security module is supposed to be able to prevent users from running the ptrace system call, yet even with kernel.yama.ptrace_scope set to 3, users can still run strace (which uses ptrace).

From the docs:

```
3 - no attach: no processes may use ptrace with PTRACE_ATTACH nor via
    PTRACE_TRACEME. Once set, this sysctl value cannot be changed.
```

The Yama module does seem to be loaded:

```
/var/log/dmesg:[    0.000127] Yama: becoming mindful.
```

This is on RHEL7, with SELinux also installed, which may be relevant.   LSMs are supposed to be stackable, and I am seeing the above message in dmesg, so it appears to be active.  As an aside, once set to 3, the sysctl value is immutable - I don't know if that implies that the Yama module is active or not.

Interestingly, on Ubuntu (without Apparmor, I believe), setting the value to 3 does prevent ptrace from running - running strace -p  (as root) gives a permission denied error.

I'm concerned, as Yama is supposed to mitigate against a couple of other vulnerabilities.

It has just occurred to me to reboot without SELinux and see if it works in that contest - I'll update once I have done so.

Is Yama deprecated (there's a SELinux boolean which handles this behaviour - it's `deny_ptrace`)?  I can find very little in the way of documentation.

**UPDATE:** (even without SElinux loaded yama does nothing)

```
Oct  2 12:30:00 xx kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/rpool-root ro crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=rpool/root rd.lvm.lv=rpool/swap rhgb ipv6.disable=1 biosdevname=0 net.ifnames=0 quiet audit=1 fips=1 boot=/dev/sda1 audit=1 CONFIG_SECURITY_YAMA=y selinux=0
Oct  2 12:30:00 xx kernel: Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/rpool-root ro crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=rpool/root rd.lvm.lv=rpool/swap rhgb ipv6.disable=1 biosdevname=0 net.ifnames=0 quiet audit=1 fips=1 boot=/dev/sda1 audit=1 CONFIG_SECURITY_YAMA=y selinux=0
Oct  2 12:30:00 xx kernel: SELinux:  Disabled at boot.
Oct  2 12:30:00 xx kernel: EVM: security.selinux
Oct  2 12:30:00 xx systemd[1]: systemd 219 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA -APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 -SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN)
Oct  2 12:30:03 xx systemd: systemd 219 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA -APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 -SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN)
```

And Yama still doesn't deny ptrace:

```
xx:root@~ #strace -p 2195
strace: Process 2195 attached
restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted poll ...>strace: Process 2195 detached
 <detached ...>
xx:root@~ #sysctl -a -r yama
kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 3
```

Comment: Not exactly related to yama, but on RHEL there is a SELinux boolean to [disable ptrace](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/sect-security-enhanced_linux-working_with_selinux-disable_ptrace).

Comment: Yeah thanks - I did mention it, but should have given the value: it's deny_ptrace.   With your advice on making selinux immutable,  we may be able to forget about Yama.  The Yama way is more flexible in that it has 3 possible values, although only '3' is immutable.

Comment: Making SELinux immutable: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/472731/is-it-possible-to-prevent-a-change-in-selinux-status-without-a-reboot